# Redirecting to a new domain and adding a variable in the address using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect my users from an old domain to a new one using htaccess but also add a variable in the address to indicate they are coming from the older domain,

here's an exampel

```
http://old.com/index.php?var1=3  ==>  http://new.com/index.php?var1=3&comingFromOld=1
http://old.com/index.php  ==>  http://new.com/index.php?comingFromOld=1
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the normal basic redirect from old to new domains would be something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To add in this extra URL variables, there are two cases we want to consider.  Firstly, some pages will already have URL variables, in which case we just want to append &comingFromOld=1.  Secondly some pages won't have any URL variables, in which case we want to append with ?comingFromOld=1 instead.

You'd expect this would maybe require either two sets of rules, or one complicated regex to allow for both cases.  Fortunately there's a nice flag we can use, QSA, that will append the original query string (if one exists).  I think this should cover you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1?comingFromOld=1  [QSA,R=301,L]
```

So you'll either end up with URLs like `http://new.com/index.php?comingFromOld=1`  or `http://new.com/index.php?comingFromOld=1&var1=3`